# Python interpreter prints legacy code upon error

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

**Introduction:**
I've just started programming in Python (my first programming language so far) and I have to say I'm quite enjoying it. I've already covered the basic topics such as classes, data types, file handling etc. Recently, something very odd and annoying started to happen though.

**What's wrong:**
Whenever I run a Python script that results in an error (no matter if syntax, indentation, etc.), it will print out the results of a previously run script before printing out the error message. Interestingly, it's always the same bit of code that's being displayed before the eventual error message. Here's the output of `python3 sys.py` (just a random script):

```
1
1.0
<class 'int'>
<class 'float'>
3.14j
<class 'complex'>
10
<class 'int'>
8
<class 'int'>
3
4
4
8
8
9
0b1000
0x8
  File "sys.py", line 10
    if line.strip() = "exit"
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 72, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 32, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 12, in <module>
    import os, glob, subprocess, os.path, time, pwd, sys, requests_unixsocket
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests_unixsocket/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/home/phil/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/home/phil/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 28, in <module>
    from ._internal_utils import to_native_string
  File "/home/phil/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compat import is_py2, builtin_str, str
  File "/home/phil/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/compat.py", line 32, in <module>
    import simplejson as json
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
    from decimal import Decimal
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/decimal.py", line 3, in <module>
    from _decimal import *
AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Number'

Original exception was:
  File "sys.py", line 10
    if line.strip() = "exit"
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The actual error of the sys.py script is irrelevant here; what bothers me is the output above it. As you can see, the Python interpreter prints out the results of another script that I wrote when first playing around with numbers and data types (hence the output contains an integer, a float, a type() call, etc. etc.) before printing out the error message relevant for the `sys.py` script.

**What I've tried:** I've tried clearing the Python cache as well as reinstalling the Python package itself. Both attempts were unsuccessful in eliminating the problem. Does anybody have any idea how this could be remediated?

Comment: shouldn't it be `if line.strip() == "exit"`

Comment: Can't really say without looking at the code. Could you post a link to your code on pastebin for us?

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the fast feedback! As stated above, the error in the ```sys.py``` script is not the problem here. It should indeed use double equal signs, but then I wouldn't get an error to show you guys ;-)

And I can definitely share the code (https://pastebin.com/Na33yJz6 here you go), but I don't think the code is the issue, as (as stated above) the error persists no matter the code I am running. It seems the issue is with the interpreter/Python package itself.